# Set elements from array pointer into protobuf in C++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I have a pointer to an array called `array` which is defined as `uint16_t *array`. I have another variable called `size` that shows how many elements there is. I have a field in a protobuf message defined as:

```protobuf
required bytes array = 1;
```

How can I use the generated method `protoMessage.set_array` to convert my array into the field?

Edit:

I realized I could do `protoMessage.set_array(array, sizeof(uint16_t) * size);` to put the data in, still unsure about how to properly set it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Protobuf's `bytes` type is a `std::string`, you need to serialize your `uint16_t` array into a string, and calls `set_array`.

```
protoMessage.set_array(array, sizeof(uint16_t) * size);
```

However, your serialization might not be portable, because of the big/little endian problem.

In your case, why not define your proto message field as `repeated`? So that you can put your uint16_t array into the field, and protobuf will do the serialization work for you.

```
repeated uint32 array = 1;
```

```
protoMessage.mutable_array()->Add(array, array + size);
```